# Python 2.6 Installation Error: "There was no software found to install

Tags: python, macos, installation, python-2.x, python-2.6

When I try to install Python 2.6, specifically Python 2.6.5, after trying to install I get a message saying "The installation failed.

The Installer could not install the software.

The Installer could not install the software because there was no software found to install."

I have seen ways of getting around this by installing Python 2 in the terminal, but that gives python 2.7, not 2.6.

What can I do to install it without having this error?

Comment: Add what you try for 2.7?

Comment: Maybe you are using a corrupt file...

Comment: Where did you get the 2.6.5 from?  Which OS?

Comment: @Himanshu sharma I am avoiding Python 2.7, which downloads fine, because it can only be used with Pygame for Python 2.7 which has a bug stopping me from optimising my program.

Comment: @cdarke I have got all of my downloads from the python website, I think it may have something to do with the fact that my MacOs already has some internal version of python so it will not let me install the IDLE version.

Comment: @Leonardo Alves Machado I feel that the python website downloads are not corrupted, but incase they are, do you know anywhere else I could download python 2.6.5 or really any python 2.6?

Comment: @PatrickHume31: I really would avoid `2.6`, have you considered using `python 3` instead, you know you will have to upgrade eventually.

Comment: @cdarke I have used python 3 before, when I wasn't on a Mac. But now I'm using a Mac, there is a bug with Pygame that is present when using python 3 and 2.7. Perhaps trying to fix that bug is a better idea than going all the way back to 2.6.5.

Comment: Fixing the bug is most certainly a better way, but of course it depends on your deadlines and whose bug it is.

Comment: @cdarke It is a small problem with Pygame (specifically on the MacOS) that has quite a large effect on my optimisation, I think fixing it would take time. I have no urgent deadlines, but I just want to write programs like many others. Maybe I should just switch to a different GUI, although I am very comfortable with Pygame and it does everything I need it to.